# DAO updates database in one method but doesn't in other

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a DAO whose implementation uses a JPA entity manager, along with springs @Transactional . I have an `addOrUpdate` method which persists a new entity to the db or updates an existing one and that seems to be working fine. I have another method called `removeById` which doesn't actually delete an entity form the db but is supposed to only invalidate it by setting it's state to inactive ('I'). However upon calling `removeById` no updates are being done to the database. Why?

Here's the DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao {   

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    LocationDao locationDao;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<ClientDTO> findAll() {

        List<Client> clientsDb = entityManager.createQuery(
                "from Client c where c.state = 'A'").getResultList();

        List<ClientDTO> clients = null;

        if (clientsDb != null) {
            clients = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Client client : clientsDb) {
                clients.add(ClientDTO.entityToDto(client));
            }
        }

        return clients;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientDTO findById(long id) {
        Client clientDb = entityManager.find(Client.class, id);
        ClientDTO client = null;
        if (clientDb != null) {
            client = ClientDTO.entityToDto(clientDb);
        }
        return client;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientDTO addOrUpdate(ClientDTO dto) {

        Client clientDb = null;
        if (dto.getId() == 0) {
            clientDb = new Client();
            clientDb.setLocation(new ArrayList<Location>());
            clientDb.setState('A');
        } else {
            clientDb = entityManager.find(Client.class, dto.getId());
            if (clientDb == null) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Client Entity with id "
                        + dto.getId() + " could not be found!");
            }
        }

        clientDb.setName(dto.getName());
        clientDb.setAddress(dto.getAddress());
        clientDb.setCode(dto.getCode());
        clientDb.setOib(dto.getOib());
        clientDb.setExternId(dto.getExternId());
        clientDb.setDateFrom(dto.getDateFrom());
        clientDb.setDateTo(dto.getDateTo());

        clientDb.getLocation().clear();

        for (LocationDTO locationDto : dto.getLocation()) {

            locationDto = locationDao.addOrUpdate(locationDto);         

            Location locationDb = entityManager.find(Location.class,
                    locationDto.getId());

            if (locationDb == null) {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException("Location Entity with id "
                        + locationDto.getId() + " could not be found!");
            }                               

            clientDb.getLocation().add(locationDb);

        }

        if (clientDb.getId() == 0) {
            entityManager.persist(clientDb);
        }

        return ClientDTO.entityToDto(clientDb);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(ClientDTO entity) {
        removeById(entity.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void removeById(long id) {

        Client clientDb = entityManager.find(Client.class, id);

        if (clientDb != null) {
            clientDb.setState('I');
            for (Location location : clientDb.getLocation()) {
                locationDao.removeById(location.getId());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void testRemove() {
    //prepare
    //execute
    clientDao.removeById(1);
    //assert
    assertThat(clientDao.findAll()).hasSize(0);
}
```

Test result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected size:<0> but was:<1> for <[com.redacted.dto.ClientDTO@e542e8ee]>
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failure(Fail.java:228)
    at org.fest.assertions.Assert.failure(Assert.java:149)
    at org.fest.assertions.GroupAssert.hasSize(GroupAssert.java:89)
    at com.redatcted.dao.ClientDaoTest.testRemove(ClientDaoTest.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Please provide mappings for `Client` and `Location` classes.
Also is your test transnational?

Comment: Please add `assertThat(clientDao.findAll()).hasSize(1)` prior removeById

Comment: Test is transactional and `assertThat(clientDao.findAll()).hasSize(1)` before removeById passes.

What exactly do you mean by mappings for `Client` and `Location` classes? Want me to provide the JPA entities?

Comment: yes, please add `Client` and `Location` classes and the way you mapped them (xml/annotations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp! Found the culprit.

Every single entity extends a mapped superclass called ModelBase, and In that ModelBase is a little bit of code which caused me great confusion.

The code:

```
@PreUpdate
private void preUpdate() {
    edited = LocalDateTime.now();

    if (state != 'A' || state != 'I') {
        state = 'A';
    }
}
```

Can you spot it? 
Yes the `||` is supposed to be `&&`. Whenever I'd set the state to 'I', before updating the table `preUpdate` would get called, see that the first clause(`state != 'A'`) was false and promptly set the state back to 'A'.

The best thing about all this? I wrote that code.

Many thanks to everyone who tried to help.

P.S.: Before anybody asks why I'm using a char as a state instead of boolean, the answer is that there will be multiple states in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you are missing

```
 entityManager.persist(clientDb);
```

which you have used in your addOrUpdate method.

LocationDao implementation is required in order to comment on removeById. You shall however simply clear location list from Parent record ClientDb and call for delete orphans

Comment: Hm. Isn't `persist` for entities we are certain are new? In `addOrUpdate` method I've used `persist` only when the entity is a new one, however updates still work without need for explicit `merge` call. In `removeById` however neither `persist` nor `merge` seem to do anything.

Comment: I guess you are right about usage of persist (i am used to wrapper templates, not very much on entitymanager methods).  I guess you need an explicit merge call. Are you sure on your Junit test btw, because you are not actually deleting clientDb however your assertmethod seem to look for it

Comment: I'm asserting findAll method which returns only the entities which have an active state. Anyway, I fixed the issue. It was a misplaced `||` of all things.